# Microsoft SQL Server only cursor

Tags: sql-server

I want to get advanced with using Cursor, only. I have a small table below and basically what I want to do is write a cursor in MS SQL Server to compare two date records. If the difference is less than 5 days between the two dates then I want to keep the earlier of the two dates. If both dates are more than 5 days apart then I want to keep both and the cursor should continue comparing the next record and so on. However it's not working as I intended. The output that I am looking for from the Cursor is a table called Final14 with the records that has the word "Keep" next to it.

I added a third column to show which date should be kept.

**SQL Columns**

```
Name    Date    
Mary    2/2/2016    Keep
Mary    2/3/2016    Delete
Mary    2/5/2016    Keep
Mary    2/11/2016   keep
Mary    2/17/2016   Keep
Mary    2/19/delete delete
```

My Cursor below:

```
/*
CREATE TABLE FIND14 --DROP TABLE FIND14
(
    Name NVARCHAR(20)
    , DATE1 DATETIME
)
;

CREATE TABLE FINAL14
(
    Name NVARCHAR(20)
    , DATE1 DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO FIND14(Name, DATE1)
VALUES('Mary', '2/2/2016'), ('Mary', '2/3/2016'), ('Mary', '2/5/2016'), ('Mary', '2/11/2016')
, ('Mary', '2/17/2016'), ('Mary', '2/19/2016')
*/

TRUNCATE TABLE FINAL14;

DECLARE @Member1 NVARCHAR(20), @SD1 DATETIME
DECLARE @Member2 NVARCHAR(20), @SD2 DATETIME

DECLARE CDATE CURSOR
FOR

    SELECT Name, DATE1
    FROM FIND14 

    ORDER BY DATE1

OPEN CDATE

    FETCH NEXT FROM CDATE INTO @Member1, @SD1 
    FETCH NEXT FROM CDATE INTO @Member2, @SD2 

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

    BEGIN

        IF DATEDIFF(dd, @SD1, @SD2) < 5

            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO FINAL14

                    SELECT @Member1, @SD1
                    FROM FIND14

            END

        ELSE 

            IF DATEDIFF(dd, @SD1, @SD2) >= 5

            BEGIN

                    INSERT INTO FINAL14

                    SELECT DISTINCT @Member1, @SD1
                    FROM FIND14
                    ;

                    INSERT INTO FINAL14

                    SELECT DISTINCT @Member2, @SD2
                    FROM FIND14

            END

FETCH NEXT FROM CDATE INTO @Member1, @SD1
END

CLOSE CDATE
DEALLOCATE CDATE
;

SELECT * FROM FIND14
```

;

OUTPUT should look like this:

```
Name    Date    
Mary    2/2/2016    Keep
Mary    2/5/2016    Keep
Mary    2/11/2016   keep
Mary    2/17/2016   Keep
```

Comment: What is the question? Besides, advanced users avoid cursors like the plague as the are hundreds of times slower than the equivalent SQL statements. Another reason is that cursors are very hard to read

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!  Cursors should be used as a last resort.  SQL is a set based languages and works best with set based approaches.  There are very few occasions when a cursor is actually needed (some would argue there are none).

Comment: Should  *2/17/2016 Keep* be *2/17/2016 Delete*?

Comment: The most advanced use of cursors is to **avoid them** whenever possible (and it's possible in 90+% of the cases...)

Comment: Why do you want to keep 2/5/2016?   It's less than 5 days after 2/2/2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your inserts, since you are inserting only variables, use VALUES instead of SELECT:

```
                INSERT INTO FINAL14
                VALUES (@Member1, @SD1)
                ;
```

**EDIT:**

Okay, now that I understand that you always want to skip to the next PAIR of rows after doing a comparison, then you just need to add a line at the end of your loop to fetch the next PAIR of rows, and not just the next row.  So you need to replace this:

```
    FETCH NEXT FROM CDATE INTO @Member1, @SD1 
END
```

With this:

```
    FETCH NEXT FROM CDATE INTO @Member1, @SD1 
    FETCH NEXT FROM CDATE INTO @Member2, @SD2 
END
```

Just like you do before you start the loop.

Comment: Thanks but the output is still not as expected.

Comment: That's because your expected output doesn't match your logic.  You still haven't explained why you want to keep `2/5/2016` when it goes against your requirement of "less than 5 days from the previously kept date".

Comment: Let me try to re-explain... The cursor should look at the first date which is 2/2/2016 and compare it to the next date which is 2/3/2016... the difference of days between them is less then 5 so I want to keep 2/2/2016. Good so far? Now the cursor should move to 2/5/2016 and compare to the next date which is 2/11/2016... since both date are 5 days apart I want to keep both 2/5/2016 and 2/11/2016. Now the cursor should move to 2/17/2016 and compare that with 2/19/2016... since the difference is less than 5 days then I want to keep 2/17/2016 which the  earlier of the two dates

Comment: No problem, please close the question by clicking the checkmark on the upper left side of this answer.   : )